# Error "Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas" for simple view function

Tags: solidity, web3js, ganache, solidity-0.8.x, mocha

I am trying to compile, deploy and run a function for a simple Ethereum contract, but when I run the function(a simple `view` function that returns an `int`) it says that I ran out of gas:

```
$ npm run test

> campaignstarter@0.1.0 test
> mocha

  Newspaper
    1) function call

  0 passing (131ms)
  1 failing

  1) Newspaper
       function call:
     Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
      at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:297:15)
      at ABICoder.decodeParameters (node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:284:17)
      at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:481:22)
      at Method.outputFormatter (node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:788:42)
      at Method.formatOutput (node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:147:54)
      at sendTxCallback (node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:530:33)
      at /home/iuliu/Work/blockchain/timpul/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:307:9
      at /home/iuliu/Work/blockchain/timpul/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:42:14963
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I am using a local `Ganache` test network.
I was able to run the deployed contract from the `Remix IDE` by using the deployed address, e.g. `0x39F75F1b61ea78E7ba0aFb3e0FEBAa0DFac510B5`, but I can't get it to work using `web3js`. None of the solutions found online worked for me.

Here is the source code that I use:

###### Newspaper.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract Newspaper {
    function getData() external view returns(int) {
        return m_data;
    }

    int private m_data = 42;
}
```

###### compile.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

console.log("Compiling sources with:", solc.version());

const newspaperPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Newspaper.sol');

const newspaperSource = fs.readFileSync(newspaperPath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Newspaper.sol' : {
            content: newspaperSource
        },
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};

output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

const contracts = output.contracts;

for (let contractFile in contracts) {
    for (let contractData in contracts[contractFile]) {
        fs.outputJsonSync(
            path.resolve(buildPath, contractData + '.json'),
            contracts[contractFile][contractData]
        );
    }
}
```

###### deploy.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const newspaper = require('./build/Newspaper.json');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'then demise coast praise when web glow correct group lawsuit leopard slow',
    'HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'
)

const web3 = new Web3(provider)

const deploy = async() => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0])

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(newspaper.abi)
        .deploy({
            data: newspaper.evm.bytecode.object
        })
        .send({
            gas: '5000000',
            from: accounts[0]
        })

    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
    provider.engine.stop();
};

deploy();
```

###### Newspaper.test.js:

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const compiledNewspaper = require('../ethereum/build/Newspaper.json');

let newspaper;

beforeEach(async() => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    newspaper = await new web3.eth.Contract(
        compiledNewspaper.abi,
        '0x39F75F1b61ea78E7ba0aFb3e0FEBAa0DFac510B5'
    );
});

describe('Newspaper', () => {
    it('function call', async() => {
        const newspaperName = await newspaper.methods.getData().call();
        console.log("Newspaper name:", newspaperName);
    });
});
```

Any idea why it complains about the lack of gas if all I doo is just calling a view function? Can someone point to a place where I don't use the API correctly?

Comment: why arent you using Truffle or hardhat for developing and testing? it does make all the works for you and you will end up just writing 2 or 3 lines?

Comment: @MajdTL Am I not using the truffle HDWalletProvider?

Comment: @MajdTL Could you point me to a guide or example that does this simpler?

Comment: Are you just trying to develop and test a smart contact? if yes then please check hardhat framework and it makes your live much easier and no need to write things like compile.js and complicated deploy.js. here are some links to start https://hardhat.org/getting-started/   and https://dev.to/stermi/how-to-deploy-your-first-smart-contract-on-ethereum-with-solidity-and-hardhat-5efc 
 and https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/solidity-tutorial-hardhat-nfts/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qpi80dQsGU